# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'?

Tags: python, tkinter

Basically, I created another window when the #Topscores method is called. In this window there is a listbox and a Sort button.

When i click the Sort button, it suppose to sort the values in the listbox, however whenever i clicked on the Sort button, it shows

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'

on this line of code

```
temp_list = list(topscoreslistbox.get(0,END))
```

Anyone can help me with this?

By the way how the Listbox gets its values is from the #TopscoresStop method.

```
def main():
        root = Tk()
        root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        root.title("Solar Car Racing")
        root.geometry("1600x900")
        topscoreslistbox = 0

        sw = StopWatch(root)
        sw.place(x=120, y=80)

        sw2 = StopWatch2(root)
        sw2.place(x=840, y=80)

    def Topscores():
        toplevel() = Toplevel()
        toplevel.title("Top Scores")
        topscoreslistbox = Listbox(toplevel, selectmode=EXTENDED, height=3, width=20, font=("Helvetica", 26))                   
        topscoreslistbox.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH, expand=1, pady=5, padx=2)

        first = Label(toplevel, text=("1st"), font=("Algerian", 30))
        first.pack(side=TOP)

        second = Label(toplevel, text=("2nd"), font=("Algerian", 30))
        second.pack(side=TOP)     

        third = Label(toplevel, text=("3rd"), font=("Algerian", 30))
        third.pack(side=TOP)  

        Buttonsort = Button(toplevel, text="Sort", command=Sort)
        Buttonsort.pack()        

    def TopscoresStop():
        tempo = sw._elapsedtime - sw.lapmod2
        tempo2 = sw2._elapsedtime2 - sw2.lapmod2

            if sw._running:
                sw.after_cancel(sw._timer)            
                sw._elapsedtime = time.time() - sw._start    
                sw._setTime(sw._elapsedtime)
                sw._running = 0

            if len(sw.laps) == 3:
                return

            sw.laps.append(sw._setLapTime(tempo))
            topscoreslistbox.insert(END, (str(sw.one.get()) , "%.2f" % sw._elapsedtime))
            topscoreslistbox.yview_moveto(1)

            if sw2._running2:
                sw2.after_cancel(sw2._timer2)            
                sw2._elapsedtime2 = time.time() - sw2._start2    
                sw2._setTime(sw2._elapsedtime2)
                sw2._running = 0

            if len(sw2.laps) == 3:
                return

            sw2.laps.append(sw2._setLapTime(tempo))
            topscoreslistbox.insert(END, (str(sw.two.get()) , "%.2f" % sw2._elapsedtime2))
            topscoreslistbox.yview_moveto(1)

    def Sort():
        temp_list = list(topscoreslistbox.get(0,END))
        temp_list.sort()
        topscoreslistbox.delete(0, END)
        for item in temp_list:
            topscoreslistbox.insert(END, item)
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your indentations, please, correct it. Also, you are initializing `topscoreslistbox` with zero in `main` function. Could this be the root of the problem?

Comment: If i do not initialize it with zero, it will shows global name 'topscoreslistbox' is not defined

Comment: Any ideas on how could it be done?

Comment: what do you mean? By the way i am new to python

Comment: Where is the `topscoreslistbox` defined? May be wrapping all functions with class is a solution? You could make `topscoreslistbox` member of a class and then initialize it with calling `Topscores`. Also you have very strange line `toplevel() = Toplevel()`. I guess, there should be no brackets after `toplevel`

Comment: It is confusing me. Sorry i make a typo error on that line. it should not have any brackets. the #topscoreslistbox i never defined it anywhere

Comment: Well, let's define major problems in your code. Firstly, your indentation is broken. Secondly, you misunderstanding the way functions communicating with variables. You should firstly develop your architecture: just pick up pen and write on paper all required functions and relationships between them. Only after that you should write code. And I also suggest you to learn, how classes are working in Python